# Designing a banner advertisement

Tags: website-design, design-principles, advertising

I have to create a 728*90 pixels banner advertisement for a website that has a product image and text. The product image I have is a 5mb .tiff file. What program should I use to create the advert? I don't have PhotoShop. I have tried creating on GIMP, Inkscape (converting raster to vector for product image) and PowerPoint, but I am losing quality in the product image.

Comment: There's no way for us to help us given the current lack of information. Please try editing your question to include all relevant details for us to understand the issue, what you did to get up unto the point of that issue, and any other relevant information

Comment: It can *often* be helpful to reduce large raster images in stages (barring Photoshop's Smart Objects). Reduce the large image in steps... to 75%... then 75% of the new size... then again 75% of the new size... until you are relatively close to the size you need. Doing this allows the typical raster interpolation to *not* overwhelm an image due to a massive reduction. It's difficult to provide anything more without more information. There's no inherent reason GIMP, Inkscape, or Powerpoint would *not* work.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You would have the same problem with Photoshop. 728px x 90px is a tiny thin strip of an image. What size is the image you are trying to use? And what size are you trying to resize it to? Can you show us what your tried/what went wrong. Resampling an image to make it smaller will always degrade image quality to some degree.  Why do you need to use a product image in such a thin banner?  You may have to rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter with what program you make that. That size of pixels is TINY!

Gimp is ok. What you get is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free trial for Photoshop or Illustrator.
In addition, there are a huge number of programs that work with graphics:

- Gimp
- Apple Photos
- Pixlr
- Figma
- Luminar
- and more...

The main point is what file format you need and what skills you have to work with these tools.
I guess you creating Ads for Google so, info about Ad's requirements you can find here - https://support.google.com/google-ads/editor/answer/57755?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisplay-ads